# How to get the approximation of $\ln 2$?

Tags: approximation

How to get the approximation of $\ln 2$ and prove results using the knowledge of senior high school(China)[See in the textbook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iyl0d.jpg).(the figure accurate to the third decimal place)?
Above the question,everything we are supposed to use(without proving):

1. derivative and its main formulas to find a function's derivative
2. definite integral
3. Newton-Leibniz formula

---

In fact,there's an orignal question about it.[See it in the picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T16ET.jpg)

---

So,I find a method to calculate it.But it is slowly to use actually.[And the official answer is so ingenious to construct a fit inequality.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfFSc.jpg)
I use the definite integral.

Since$$lnx=\int\frac{1}xdx$$ then according to the Newton-Leibniz formula:$$ln2=ln2-ln1=\int_1^2 \frac{1}xdx$$
Then the interval 1 to 2 is then divided into ten parts and approximated using the connection of the points of $\frac{1}x$ at the endpoints of the interval.It's hard to calculate and its approximation only accurate to the second decimal place.

Comment: It's the unique $x$ for which $e^x=2.$ First since $e^0=1<2<e^1=2.718...,$ one knows it lies in interval $[0,1].$ Then do bisection method enough times to trap it to the accuracy needed.

Comment: One pretty easy approach amounts to "range reduction" $\ln 2 = \ln(e(2/e)$ as covered in [this previous Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/517848/prove-that-lne2-e-is-a-fast-way-to-calculate-ln2).  If a high precision result were needed,  then continued fractions are better than the well known power series, which for $\ln 2$ involves the infamously slowly converging *alternating harmonic series*.  See the last part of [this older Answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/18517/3111) of mine for details.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Newton's Method for approximating roots of an equation. Consider:

$f(x) = e^x - 2$

When $x = \ln(2)$, $f(x) = 0$, so:

Make a guess, say $x_0=1$, then Newton's Method says:

$x_{n+1}=x_n-f(x_n)/f'(x_n)$

$x_1 = x_0 - f(x_0)/f'(x_0)$
$= 1 - (e-2)/e$

Then:

$x_2 = x_1 - f(x_1)/f'(x_1)$

When you get to $x_3$ it's accurate to 6 decimal places ($x_2$ is accurate to 2).

Alternatively, you can use the power series representation of $\ln(1+x)$:

$\ln(1+x) = x-x^2/2+x^3/3-x^4/4+...$

Evaluating at $x=1$ gives you a rational approximation, but it's only accurate to three decimal places after 500 terms