# Finding e^x with more number of significant digits using a previously computed value of the same (having lesser number of significant digits)

Tags: algorithms

Suppose I have found an irrational number, say *e^x* upto *m* decimal places....

Now I want to find upto say *m+n* decimal places. Is there any way that I can use the previous value of *e^x* upto *m* decimal places to *help* me find the remaining *n* decimal places? (I can save some number, say, like remainder, when finding upto *m* decimal places to help me find the later digits...)

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5420/iterative-refinement-algorithm-for-computing-expx-with-arbitrary-precision

Comment: It probably depends on how you calculated the first $m$ decimal places. If you did it using the series you could just continue adding smaller terms to increase your accuracy.

Comment: @user3123.. how can I continue adding terms, because the previously computed terms won`t be of the required accuracy...

Answer (score 1):

In general, it depends on $x$. There are cases where knowing some digits will give you a head start at finding more digits. An example is $\sqrt{2} = e^{0.5\ln(2)}$, which is a root of $f(x) = x^2-2 = 0$. One improves the accuracy of the approximation $a_n$ by using [Newton's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method):
$$ a_{n+1} = a_n - \frac{f(a_n)}{f'(a_n)} =  a_n - \frac{x^2-2}{2x}$$